# In source tag ng-source is not working for dynamic video?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to display video in thumbnail  which is coming from angular controller(dynamically from server side) but  ng-source is not able to take url path but it will work fine when i give direct url path.

This is my controller code .

```
 $scope.items = {
        "media": [{
            "type": "img",
            "big": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/"
        }, {
            "type": "video",
            "thumb": "https://player.vimeo.com/external/158148793.hd.mp4?s=8e8741dbee251d5c35a759718d4b0976fbf38b6f&profile_id=119&oauth2_token_id=57447761",
        }]
    };


 });
```

and Html code

```
<div id="slider" class="container" ng-style="vm.navPosStyle" ng-repeat="image in items.media">
                   <img ng-src="{{image.big}}"  class="galleryItem" 
                        click="vm.setImage( image.big )"/>
                    <video class="galleryItem" ng-if="image.type === 'video'" width="320" height="240">
                        <source ng-src="{{image.thumb}}" type="video/mp4" ng-click="vm.setImage( image.thumb )">
                    </video> 
                </div>
```

problem is

```
<video class="galleryItem" ng-if="image.type === 'video'" width="320" height="240">
                        <source ng-src="{{image.thumb}}" type="video/mp4" ng-click="vm.setImage( image.thumb )">
                    </video>
```

source tag is not working

Comment: Only the source tag is not working? Everything else is ok?

Comment: Can you please provide a plunkr so that its easy for people to fix it?

Comment: yes only source tag is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is blocking your resource from what it thinks is an untrusted source.

According to Angular,

> By default, only URLs that belong to the same origin are trusted. These are urls with the same domain, protocol and port as the application document.

Overcoming this issue is relatively simple, you need to tell your Angular application that the source is indeed a trusted one by using `$sce`.

Let's create a filter that will do just that:

```
app.filter('trustResource', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(url) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    }
}]);
```

Inside of your HTML you can simply use

```
ng-src="{{image.thumb | trustResource}}"
```

[image]